# How do I override a (css) metaclass property using a GreaseMonkey script?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey, reddit, tampermonkey

My goal here is to make a script which will remove spoiler styling from /r/avatar.

By playing around with the "inspect element" element feature of Firefox I've managed to find the code in one of the CSS sheets which makes spoilered titles transparent. It looks like this

```
html:not([lang="ns"]) .thing.over18 a.title{
opacity:0.0
}
```

I've been searching for a way to override this attribute from greasemonkey, but I'm not sure how. I'm new to javascript: I've been trying to make use of

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.thing.over18')
```

to try and grab the elements with the (meta?)class attached to them, but no matter how I play with the class name I cant get it to select the right elements (I have an inkling that I'm not using the right function now).

There was actually a script on userscripts.org which did something similar (unspoiler /r/pokemon), but it seems that userscripts has been down so I cant look at its source.

Comment: To apply custom styles you better use something like [**stylish**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) . However, setting the style for `.thing.over18` will not have an effect, because the style has been set for `a.title`

Comment: How would I override this style from greasemonkey? The only thing I can think of would be `a.css("opacity", "1")` but dropping that in the script doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "metaclass" in CSS or HTML. `.thing` is a class selector. `.over18` is another class selector. You just have two class selectors.

`getElementsByClassName` only accepts a single class name.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('thing')
document.getElementsByClassName('over18')
```

If you want to use a selector, then use `querySelector` (for a single element) or `querySelectorAll` (for a NodeList).

```
document.querySelectorAll(".thing.over18");
```

Comment: Whoops, I've allowed my python to run away with my web. I wasnt actually aware that "thing" and "over18" were two different things (probably due to the lack of a space between them." Using just "over18" allows me to grab the correct elements. Now to style them right...

Comment: One more question: I managed to grab the right (number of) elements. Logging them to the console gives something like `<div data-downs="?" data-ups="?" data-fullname="t3_2efnf3" onclick="click_thing(this)" class=" thing id-t3_2efnf3 over18 even  link ">`. They dont seem to have an `opacity` attribute, as set in the stylesheet above. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: `opacity` is a CSS property, not an HTML attribute.

Comment: Figured that out after the fact; I've actually had some success by stripping the over18 class from the elements which possess it. I say "some" because it seems extremely inconsistent. [The script](http://pastebin.com/1ZXC0yQJ) succeeds in unsploilering some posts on [the intended page](http://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender), but seems to fail to touch others. Running the script on the relevant page gives me [this output in the console](http://pastebin.com/QMTySv7v). Could you try the script out and give me some insight as to what's going wrong?

Comment: @pipsqueaker117: You're probably using a modern browser, so you can probably rely on `document.querySelectorAll` and `node.classList`. Try: `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".over18")).forEach(function (el) { el.classList.remove("over18"); });`

Comment: Code flat out does not work (I replaced the [] with spoilered ofc). Browser console says that spoilered.slice is not defined

Comment: The bizarre thing is that the script removes every other spoiler class

Comment: Problem solved: it appears that it was not enough to remove the over18 class, I also had to remove the "thing" class.